# should a .net mutex always be released prior to deallocation?

Tags: .net, vb.net, mutex

Will it cause a problem to grab a mutex (.WaitOne()) but later deallocate the mutex without first doing .ReleaseMutex()  ?

```
Sub func1()
  buf = new buf_Class
  buf.my_mutex = new mutex()

...
  my_thread as Thread = new Thread( AddressOf func2 )
...   
End sub


Sub func2()
  buf.my_mutex.WaitOne()
  ...
End sub

later in time...

Sub func3()
  buf = Nothing   ' to deallocate buf
End sub
```

Comment: Setting a reference variable to Nothing does not "deallocate" anything.  It is not thread-safe, func2 could still be using the mutex.  So intentionally avoiding ReleaseMutex() is but a band-aid on a festering wound, NullReferenceException tells you that you did it wrong.  Never shoot that messenger.  You almost surely should use SyncLock instead.

Comment: Thanks, Hans.  Yep, after 3 hours, memory leak blew up.  Deallocation not working.  Doesn't garbage collections deallocate if all references are Nothing?...  And I shall look into SyncLock vs. mutex...

Comment: The garbage collector only collects an object when it runs and when it sees that there are no more references to that object. Setting a variable to null (`Nothing`) usually doesn't help much. In this case, if you never call `ReleaseMutex()` the mutex is likely still referenced by that call to `WaitOne()` and might thus be stuck there forever.